# nodejs sequelize join 2 table using hasmany

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am new in nodejs. I am creating new app using nodejs. i want to join two table city and state using hasmany relations.

Here is my state model state.js

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('state', {    
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
      allowNull: true
    },    
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10).UNSIGNED,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    createdAt: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: true
    },
    updatedAt: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: true
    }
  }, {
    tableName: 'state'
  });
};
```

Here is my city model city.js

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('city', {
    state: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: true
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
      allowNull: true
    },    
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10).UNSIGNED,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    createdAt: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: true
    },
    updatedAt: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: true
    }
  }, {
    tableName: 'city'
  });
};
```

This is my citycontroller.js

```
let City = require('../models').city;
let State = require('../models').state;
let message = require('../../config/message');
let Boom = require('boom');

module.exports = {

    listCity: async(request,h) =>{
        let stateid = request.query.stateid;
        try{
            let searchQuery = {};           
            if(stateid) searchQuery.state = stateid;
            let listCity = await City.findAll({ where:searchQuery});            
            if(listCity.length){
                let response = {
                    "statusCode": 200,
                    "message":message.DATAFOUND,
                    "result": listCity
                };
                return h.response(response).code(200);
            }else{
                return h.response(response).code(204);
            }
        }catch(err){
            return Boom.badRequest(err.message);
        }    
    },

};
```

Output:

```
{
    "statusCode": 200,
    "message": "Data found",
    "result": [
        {
            "state": 1,
            "name": "Los Angeles",
            "id": 1,
            "createdAt": null,
            "updatedAt": null
        },
        {
            "state": 1,
            "name": "San Francisco",
            "id": 2,
            "createdAt": null,
            "updatedAt": null
        },
        {
            "state": 5,
            "name": "Southhampton",
            "id": 3,
            "createdAt": null,
            "updatedAt": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Now it listing city details only. but i need to join state details also under each city.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to select the data from the state table than define a relation in the state model.

   ```
   module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
     const state = sequelize.define('state', {    
     name: {
         type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
         allowNull: true
     },    
     id: {
         type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10).UNSIGNED,
         allowNull: false,
         primaryKey: true,
         autoIncrement: true
     },
     createdAt: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        allowNull: true
     },
     updatedAt: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        allowNull: true
     }
   }, {
     tableName: 'state'
   });

     state.associate = function(model){
         models.state.hasMany(models.city){
         foreignKey: 'state'
     }
     return state;
   }

   };
   ```
2. Or if you want to select data from the city table than define a similar hasOne relation in city table.